# Basic round robin in Perl difference between (++ / +1)

Tags: perl

Recently I was trying to make a simple round robin with Perl , and I found a behaviour that I don't understand clearly.

Here the behaviour:

```
my $a = {index => 0};
for (0 .. 10) {
    $a->{index} = ($a->{index}++) % 2;
    warn $a->{index};
}
```

The output of this code will be:

```
0,0,0,..,0
```

But if I do the "same" code replacing $a->{index}++ by $a->{index}+1 , the round robin will be fine, example

```
my $a = {index => 0};
for (0 .. 10) {
    $a->{index} = ($a->{index}+1) % 2;
    warn $a->{index};
}
```

The output will be:

```
1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0...
```

Someone can explain me the difference between ++ / +1 in this case? I find this really "ugly", because if I don't assign the result to any variable in the case "++" the code will work as expected unless I put the sum inside ().

This code will do a round robin correctly:

```
my $a = {index => 0};
for (0 .. 10) {
    warn $a->{index}++ % 2;
}
```

With () in the sum, the code will output: `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9`

```
my $a = {index => 0};
for (0 .. 10) {
    warn ($a->{index}++) % 2;
}
```

Comment: How about: `^=` to `xor`. E.g. `if ( $x ^= 1 ) { ...`

Comment: The expression `$i = $i++` won't change the value of `$i` because you are doing the assignment `$i = $i` before the post-increment `++` happens. Contrariwise, the expression `$i = $i + 1` will increment `$i` because the right-side `$i + 1` is evaluated *first* and that gets assigned to `$i`. I believe this is the crux of your troubles.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`$a->{index}+1` returns `$a->{index}+1`, while

`$a->{index}++` returns `$a->{index}` before it was changed.

`++$a->{index}` returns `$a->{index}+1`, but it makes no sense to use it in that expression since it needlessly changes `$a->{index}`.

---

> `$a->{index} = ($a->{index}+1) % 2;`

1. Say `$a->{index}` is initially `0`.
2. `$a->{index}+1` returns `1`.
3. Then you assign `1 % 2`, which is `1` to `$a->{index}`.

---

> `$a->{index} = $a->{index}++ % 2;`

1. Say `$a->{index}` is initially `0`.
2. `$a->{index}++` sets `$a->{index}` to `1` and returns `0` (the old value).
3. Then you assign `0 % 2`, which is `0` to `$a->{index}`.

---

Options:

```
$a->{index} = ( $a->{index} + 1 ) % 2;
if ($a->{index}) {
   ...
}
```

or

```
$a->{index} = $a->{index} ? 0 : 1;
if ($a->{index}) {
   ...
}
```

or

```
$a->{index} = !$a->{index};
if ($a->{index}) {
   ...
}
```

or

```
if (++$a->{index} % 2) {
   ...
}
```

or

```
if ($a->{index}++ % 2) {
   ...
}
```

Note that the last two options leaves an ever-increasing value in `$a->{index}` rather than `0` or `1`.

Note that the last two options differ in whether the condition will be true or false on the first pass.

Comment: A good rule of thumb is to never write `$var = ... ++$var...` or `$var = ... $var++...`.

Comment: Possible 4th option: `$a->{index} = !$a->{index}`  Pros: Less ugly than 1st option & less risk of overflow on **long** running tasks than 2nd & 3rd.  Con: `''` vs. `0` ( or `2` or `4`...) could be important in string contexts.

Comment: In the worse case, it'll only fail after 2**53 increments. There hasn't been that many microseconds since unix was invented in 1970.